# SVG feColorMatrix - the theory please

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to use a svg-filter "feColorMatrix" with a duotone-look to images of mine. Basically exactly the way it is described here: https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/

So I do have a filter of:

```
<svg class="filter-blau">
  <filter id="duotone" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
          x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="0.90 0 0 0   0.40
              0.95 0 0 0  -0.10
             -0.20 0 0 0   0.65
                0  0 0 1   0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

I do understand this thing as the first column is the starting gradients' color and the last column is the ending gradients' color, both using rgb percentage values.

Could you point me how to use these 2 values as start and endpoint:

```
rgb(95%,35%,44%)
rgb(11%,11%,72%)
```

into that example please?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong feColorMatrix works like this: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement

Comment: [Amelia's article on creating duotone filters](https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/) will probably be useful to you. As will [this more general introduction to using feColorMatrix](http://alistapart.com/article/finessing-fecolormatrix).